# difference between hash code and reference or address of an object?

Tags: java, reference, hashcode

difference between hash code and reference or address of an object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JavaME, these three things are unrelated.

An object's hashCode is a semi-unique identifier for it.

A reference to an object is a scoped handle on that object.

An object's address is (probably) unobtainable, and certainly useless.

Comment: Definitely useful. What if you want to store something in `TreeMap`, but don't care about the particular order? If you could get the reference of the object, and compare that you could use `TreeMap` for every object.

Answer (score 0):

The address of/reference to an object points to the location in memory that an Object lives.

A Hash Code is generated via a hashing algorithm and is used to identify objects in a hash collection. Different algorithms will produce different codes (poor algorithms will result in poor hash codes and more collisions in the collection).

Answer (score 0):

The hash code of an object and it's adress in memory are not related in any way. It's just that different implementations of objects (in different languages, actually) use the memory adress of an object as a unique way of identifying that object.

In general, the method pair `hashCode` and `equals` provide the means to compare objects for identity. When implementing your own hashing scheme, you should keep in mind that the hash value should be composed of something that makes the object unique. For example, imagine you provide an object mapper to a database system and want to introduce a `Customer` object - you know that in your table, customers are unique with respect to their primary key, so returning this primary key as a hash code would be perfectly acceptable and not in any way related to the object's memory adress.

If a customer is identified using his first name, lastname and birth date (which is not really enough to identify a person uniquely, but let's keep it simple for the sake of brevity) then you could hash those 3 values into a hash code and use that in your O/R mapping implementation.

Answer (score 0):

See Object's hashcode and reference are two different things.You can say in simple words, that reference of a object is path by which you will find your object in memory (or simply location of object in memory). But the hashcode is a integer value which tells Whether your object is unique or not i.e Whether it contain same data as of another object in memory or  have different data( Unique).
See the below code, we will understand it by creating two objects of String class :

```
    String str = "StackOver";
    String str2 = new String("StackOver");
    System.out.println(str.hashCode());
    System.out.println(str2.hashCode());
```

In this  , two objects will be created. Since both objects are at different location in memory that is why they  have different reference,which will get stored in str and str2. But objects have same value , so they will have same hashcode.

Note:Creating  string object with the 'new' keyword will always create a new object in memory ,even if you have a  another string object with same value.