# difference between Object reference and Object hash code

Tags: java

whats the difference between an Object's reference and the same object's  hash code value in java ?

Comment: [difference between hash code and reference or address of an object?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700595/difference-between-hash-code-and-reference-or-address-of-an-object) is the same, even though it was originally asked for Java ME.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are completely two different concepts.

```
Cat oldCat = new Cat();
Cat newCat = new Cat();
Cat oldCatRef = oldCat;
```

In the above example, `oldCat` and `oldCatRef` are references to the same object. Since they refer to the same object, their hashcodes will be equal.

But `oldCat` and `newCat` do not refer to the same object. They are references to two different objects. But they might have the same `hashCode` based on their implementation. `hashCode` is simply a method in `Object` class which you can override.

**EDIT** (from PeterJ):
According to the JavaSE6 Object specification, if oldCat.equals(newCat) then the hashcode of the two should be equal. It's good programming to obey by that contract

You probably want to check the answers for this question as well:

> [difference between hash code and reference or address of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700595/difference-between-hash-code-and-reference-or-address-of-an-object)

Comment: According to the JavaSE6 Object specification, if oldCat.equals(newCat) then the hashcode of the two should be equal. It's good programming to obey by that contract.

Answer (score 7):

A reference to an Object is just that. A reference to an Object.

An Object's hashcode is the result of the `hashCode()` method which depending on implementation may be various things. The default `hashCode()`:

> is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the JavaTM programming language

Comment: On 64-bit JVMs the references will typically use 8-bytes, the hashCode() is only 32-bits.

Answer (score 3):

Two different Objects can have same `hashCode`. A `reference` is a unique pointer to an object where `hashCode` is a convenient computed attribute.