# How == returns false even though two Strings s1 and s3 having same hashcode?

Tags: java, string

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str1 = "java";
    String str2 = str1.intern();
    String str3 = new String(str1.intern());
    System.out.println("hash1=" + str1.hashCode());
    System.out.println("hash2=" + str2.hashCode());
    System.out.println("hash3=" + str3.hashCode());
    System.out.println("str1==str2==>>" + (str1 == str2));
    System.out.println("str1==str3==>>" + (str1 == str3));
}
```

============================================output===>
hash1=3254818
hash2=3254818
hash3=3254818
str1==str2==>>**true**
str1==str3==>>**false**

=================================

Can anyone explain how == returns **false** even though **s1** and **s3** having **same** hashcode?

Comment: This happens because a `String` is an `Object`, not a primitive.  Use `.equals()`

Comment: Same `hashCode` does not mean the objects are identical (`==`), they need not even be equal (`.equals()`).

Comment: Because `==` compare the objects references, not the `hashCode` .

Comment: @UmaisGillani, I guess that memory reference value and hashcode value are different. Is it so?

Comment: You need to use `.equals()`, but you could still have two strings that are not equal that have the same hash code.  There are only 2^32 possible hash codes and many, many more possible strings than that.

Comment: Just FYI, I've never seen `String#intern` be a valid solution to a problem. Don't use it unless you know what you're doing and have an important reason to use it.

Comment: To all people trying to close this as a duplicate of "How do I compare strings in Java?" I don't think it is. The OP seems to believe the same hash code implies the objects are equal (or identical). This is a different issue.

Comment: @Tibrogargan, thanks for help for making use of `equals` method, But I can't use this because, it was an interview question. So I need a proper reason for this.

Comment: @RohitGaikwad ... awkward

Comment: @RohitGaikwad these are two different things, please have a look [Object reference and hashcode diff](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568896/difference-between-object-reference-and-object-hash-code). or correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @Makoto Agreed, did I say something different? The same hash code does not imply equals. So you may get false even if you use `.equals()` instead of `==` (not in this example, but in general). Therefore it's not a duplicate.

Comment: I'll tentatively reopen this question since you're looking more for a proper reasoning to this.  To avoid the direct spoiler, I'll abstain from answering, but the biggest clue would be in the source code for `String.equals`.

Comment: `str3` is a new `String` - that is, not the same `String` object as `str1` or `str2`.  Because you used `new` to create it, and the JVM did what you told it to do.

Comment: @RohitGaikwad Funnily enough, the Java documentation only implies that `==` should only be used for primitives, although it's probably more correct to say that `==` should only be used on `values`.  Since the "value" of any Object is really a memory address, the result you get from comparing two objects with `==` makes perfect sense.  If you want to get actual equivalence, you need to compare the contents of the Objects (using `.equals()`/`.hashCode()`)  BTW, you shouldn't get hired.

Comment: @DavidWallace, thanks for this. Actually I know this concept of Strings in java. But the interviewer tried to deceive me why it returns false even though s1 and s3 have same hashcode.

Comment: Well, if you understand that `s1` and `s3` are not the same object, then what is your question?

Comment: "If hashcodes of two objects are equals, that may not mean that objects are equals"

Answer (score 3):

Despite the comments above, I suspect that you already understand that `==` determines if two references point to the same object (or are both null), and that you should use `equals()` if you want to compare two strings for data-equality.

Rather, I think what you're missing is that the `hashCode()` method corresponds to the `equals()` method in this respect; it's based on the data in an object, and in fact, it's specified that classes should always implement `hashCode()` in such a way that if `a.equals(b)`, then `a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()`. (Of course, there's nothing in the language that enforces this.) The analogue of `==` that you're looking for is [the `System.identityHashCode()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode-java.lang.Object-).

However, even there it should be noted that `System.identityHashCode()` does not *guarantee* that distinct instances will have distinct identity hash codes. (It can't, because it's possible to have more than 2<sup>32</sup> objects in a JVM at the same time . . . granted, not all JVMs support that; but nothing in the Java language specification forbids it.)

Comment: I agree on this about the guarantee. Just a counter question on this, does it mean `==` may return `true` sometimes in this case? As, sometimes it may give you the guarantee.

Comment: @RohitGaikwad: No; `a == b` will only be `true` if `a` and `b` are the same instance (or if both are `null`). This means that `a == b` can be `false` even if `System.identityHashCode(a) == System.identityHashCode(b)`: the latter can have some false positives, but the former makes a firm guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

In a correct implementation of `equals` and `hashCode` you have the following implications for two objects `a` and `b` (that are not `null`):

if `a == b` then also `a.equals(b)`

if `a.equals(b)` then also `a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()`

Both implications cannot be reversed in general.

Answer (score -1):

For two Objects the == operator compares their pointer reference.  So unless they are actually the exact same object it's never true.

Comment: It *can* be true with interned strings.

Comment: @Makoto if both strings are interned then they _are_ the exact same object.  This answer is correct.

Answer (score -1):

When you do:

```
String a = "xyz"
```

while creating the string, the JVM searches in the pool of strings if there already exists a string value `xyz`, if so 'a' will simply be a reference of that string and no new String object is created.

But if you say:

```
String a = new String("xyz")
```

you force JVM to create a new String reference, even if "xyz" is in its pool.
and `==` compares the references. That's why you are getting the false result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know this concept of Strings in java. But I need an answer for why it returns false even though s1 and s3 have same hashcode. Here, hashcode is same. Does the memory reference value and hashcode value are different? I mean what == uses (reference value or hashcode value) I think its reference value.

Comment: @RohitGaikwad yes these two are different things, as i mentioned the link in question's comment. `.equals` method compares the `hashCode` while `==` compares the references. please have a look [Object reference and hashcode diff](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568896/difference-between-object-reference-and-object-hash-code).

Comment: and `new String(` forces the JVM to create new String reference. that's why `==` will returns false.

Comment: The hash code of a `String` has no relationship at all to its address in memory.