# Comparing two equal Strings after intern() method

Tags: java, string, string-pool

Javadoc says that if in the string pool there is an equal String that the intern() method will return the String.

```
public class Demo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str1 = "Apple";
    String str2 = new String("Apple");

    System.out.println(str1.intern() == str2); //false
    System.out.println(str1 == str2.intern()); //true
} 
}
```

I expected to get true in both cases.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40480291/) (to a slightly different question) explains everything you asked about.

Comment: I assume you understand that `str1 == str2` would return false; then, given that `str1` is assigned a string literal value, [the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern()) describes that `str.intern() == str1`. Hence, `str1.intern() == str2` is the same as `str1 == str2`, hence it is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this `str1.intern()` is bringing nothing to your try...
Since `str1` is a literal string (it will be inmediatly placed in the string pool), and you are comparing it against the `str2` which is allocated on the Heap...

therefore

```
System.out.println(str1.intern() == str2);
```

will print  `false`, you are comparing the reference of a string in the stirng pool vs a string on the heap...

Answer (score 2):

```
 System.out.println(str1.intern() == str2); //false
```

In the above case you are comparing reference of interned String `"Apple"` with that of reference of another String which is on the heap (but with the same value). So, the result is "false".

```
System.out.println(str1 == str2.intern()); //true
```

In the above case, you are comparing a reference of String constants pool to a reference got by *trying to add* "Apple" to the String constants pool. SInce, "Apple" is already in the first line, this interning will return the object pointed to by str1. Hence you get true.

PS : This behavior is described in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern())

Answer (score 0):

`String.intern()` method is used to create an exact copy of `heap` `String` object in `String` constant pool. The `String objects` in the `String` constant pool are automatically interned but `String` objects in `heap` are not

```
System.out.println(firstString.intern() == secondString);//false because it will fetch exact copy of the string compare in string

System.out.println(firstString == secondString.intern());//True because it will compare firstString with fetch the second String it will check heap or not
```